# C - GTKUibuilder - Glade - g_signal_connect error

Tags: c, macos, gtk, glade

I am trying to use Glade on my project to generate a file containing windows, grid ... But I am stuck wth an error when I try to listen to event clicked on my buttons, I do not understand why :s

I got those errors..

```
 GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(test:5608): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

... for each listener.

So my file called "project_ui.ui" set in the same directory as my main.c :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Button 1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Button 2</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">2</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Button 0</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Quit</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="width">3</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

My main.c contain this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>


static void printHello (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data){
  g_print("Hello World \n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GtkBuilder *builder;
  GObject *window;
  GObject *button;

  gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

  builder = gtk_builder_new();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "project_ui.ui", NULL);

  window = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window");
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  //Button 1
  button = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Button 1");
  g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(printHello), NULL);

  //Button 2
  button = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Button 2");
  g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(printHello), NULL);

  //Button 0
  button = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Button 0");
  g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(printHello), NULL);

  //button Quit
  button = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Quit");
  g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), window);

  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

Is someone has any idea to correct it ?

Comment: I just tried to follow this sample: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s03.html

& got the exact same error... signal does not want to listen to buttons :s

Comment: According to the error message you provide `NULL` pointers. You obviously don't have a problem with connecting the signal but with retrieving the object from your GUI. You might check your return values for `NULL` poiners.

Comment: You might check return value of `gtk_builder_add_from_file` for a start. Does the builder even find your UI file at all?

Comment: So it seems I got a valid value returned from `gtk_builder_add_from_file ` (1),
but the functions `gtk_builder_get_object` return NULL.
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/33/1/1502722434-capture-d-ecran-2017-08-14-a-16-52-21.png

The compilation is Ok, errors arrive when I run the bin

Comment: sorry @Gerhardh I was editing my comment ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh I think all require headers are already set aren't they ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see any header. You are right. My bad.

Comment: If I test with your .ui file, I get result `0`. With the builder.ui from the link you mentioned, I get result `1`. You should provide a GError variable to `gtk_builder_add_from_file` to check what is wrong with your file.

Comment: When I load builder.ui from the link in my glad (3.18.3) I get a warning that the file is for gtk2 while glade is for gtk3 only. With your file I don't get a warning, but I also do not see and widgets in the UI.

Comment: If I affect to a variable GError, this variable contain NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it with my Ubuntu machine with Gtk 3.18.

When I load your file in Glade I don't get any message in the UI but I get error messages on the shell:

> (glade:2996): GladeUI-WARNING **: The file did not contain the required property "id" Under the "object" tag.

This is a good hint.
If you look in your example that you linked, you find this:

```
<object id="button2" class="GtkButton">
```

You only have this:

```
<object class="GtkButton">
```

Without the ID the gtk_builder does not know how to find this widget.

Because you use wrong value for searching your widgets:

```
button = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Button 1");
```

This is only the text shown on the button. What you need to use is the id which is missing.
The example uses this code:

```
button = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "button1");
```

Here the ID is used to retrieve the pointer to the widget.

To solve your problem you need to add IDs to your widgets and use the IDs to retrieve them instead of the text on the label.

Comment: Thanks!! That's was about 90% of the answer for my case,
In fact I had to indicate the exact path to my UI file, it's not working with relativ path :s